# Golang tour distributed pattern

Tags: go, distributed-computing

According to [this article](http://blog.golang.org/playground), the app-engine front-end and the playground back-end communicate through RPC calls. Each one of app-engine front-end instance and playground instance can be created to support scaling.

[image: Playground Infrastructure Overview]

I am asking myself what is/are the patterns (solutions) to load balance works between front-end request and back-end instance while keeping RPC.

One solution may be to use one global working queue where tasks are puts inside it with a 'Reply-To' header. This header should point to a per front-end instance queue where responses are put. Something like the following schema (from [RabbitMQ tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html)) with rpc_queue shared between back-end instances :
[image: RabbitMQ RPC format]

I am not sure this would be a good way to do especially the fact that if the shared queue is offline, the whole system fail (but how to take care of this?).

Thank you.

Comment: I think in case of Playground each "App Engine Front End" might just store the list of "Playground Service Back End" instances and randomly selects one for each request. This list is probably synchronized to the central storage, like Zookeeper, where each Back End registers itself, so that if a new Back End service spins up, it will soon start to receive requests too. Here Zookeeper becomes a single point of failure, but it supports replication.

Comment: My system works more or less along the lines of @Kluyg's explanation. Each front-end has an internal software load-balancer, that chooses a backend server to call, based on randomness, speed of response, health, etc - and just waits for the response with a simple RPC call. The list of available backends is kept in ZK.

Comment: Both of your response seems fine, but I don't see if a backend application crash, how the central configuration service (ZooKeeper) knows about this failure?

Comment: I know it's too late to answer your last question, since you already have an answer in your [article](http://hugoguiroux.blogspot.fr/2014/05/indenter-scalable-fault-tolerant.html), but just to have it here also: the backend services usually use heartbeat messages to show that they are still alive, then frontend considers using some spicific backend only if the last heartbeat is less then some TTL value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer and a follow-up of comments I received on the first post, I developed  Indenter, a small proof of concept based on the idea proposed of a service discovery daemon (I use etcd instead of ZooKeepr for simplicity however).

I wrote an article about it and release the code if someone may be interested one day:

[Indenter: a scalable, fault-tolerant, distributed web service copying the go playground architecture.](http://hugoguiroux.blogspot.fr/2014/05/indenter-scalable-fault-tolerant.html)